Number of lattices over a finite set
I'm interested in finding a general formula for the number of lattices possible over a finite set $S$ as a function of the set's cardinality.
For instance, how many lattices over $\{1, 2, 3\}$ are there? Since the set contains three elements, and a lattice is a partial order, we must count the number of ways in which we can order three elements ensuring that the supremum between any pair always exists. There are $3! = 6$ total orders which satisfy this constrain, and in this case none of the non-total orders satisfy the constraint. $\therefore$ There are $6$ possible latices over $\{1, 2, 3\}$.
The case with only three elements is simple because only total orders count and there always are $|S|!$ total orders. But as non-total orders become available, the problem becomes slightly more difficult. Is there a general form (e.g. a generating function) for the number of lattices over a set $S$ of given cardinality?
(Similar questions (e.g. this one) have been asked but none, as far I researched, related to lattices.)

A055512?

Thanks for pointing that out, it is helpful! My question still is about a general formula for that sequence.

@lafinur In the linked page, there is another link to a paper of Heitzig and Reinhold, Counting finite lattices. There they have algorithms to compute both labeled and unlabeled numbers of lattices in a $n$-element set. It seems that each value is computed using all the previous ones, so it's probably exponential time on the size $n$. They show the values up to $n=18$. The paper is kind of technical and the algorithms depend on concepts which cannot be defined in a comment.

@amrsa I appreciate the reference. I did a quick read and evidently there is no closed-form formula. Interesting paper. Thanks.

As suggested in the comments, there is no closed-form formula (yet) for the number of lattices over a finite set of $n$ elements. See this paper.
